# Compute a matrix inverse by repeatedly solving n linear systems

Tags: matlab, math, matlab-compiler, matrix-factorization

[image]

I am trying to solve this problem. But I keep getting an error.
This is my First Code.

```
% Program 3.3

function [L, U, P] = lufact(A)
[N, N] = size(A);
X = zeros(N, 1);
Y = zeros(N, 1);
C = zeros(1, N);
R = 1:N;

for p = 1: N-1
    [max1, j] = max(abs(A(p:N, p)));

    C = A(p,:);
    A(p,:) = A(j + p - 1,:);
    A(j + p -1, :) = C;
    d = R(p);
    R(p) = R(j + p -1);
    R(j + p - 1) = d;

    if A(p,p) == 0
        'A is Singular. No unique Solution'
        break
    end

    for k = p + 1:N
        mult = A(k,p)/A(p,p);
        A(k,p) = mult;
        A(k,p + 1:N) = A(k, p + 1:N) - mult *A(p, p + 1:N);
    end

    I=(1:N)'*ones(1,N,1); J=I';
    L = (I>J).*A + eye(N);
    U = (J>=I).*A;
    P = zeros(N);
for k=1:N
P(k,R(k))=1;
end
end
X(N) = Y(N)/A(N,N);

for k = N-1: -1: 1
    X(k) = (Y(k) - A(k, k+1:N)*X(k+1:N))/A(k,k);
end
```

And This is my 2nd Code which I'm using to solve this problem.

```
function B = Ques3(A)
% Computes the inverse of a matrix A
[L,U,P] = lufact(A);
N = max(size(A));
I = eye(N);
B = zeros(N);
for j = 1:N
Y = forsub(L,P*I(:,j));
B(:,j) = backsub(U,Y);
end
```

But I keep getting an error in MATLAB,

```
>> Ques3(A)
Unrecognized function or variable 'forsub'.
Error in Ques3 (line 12)
Y = forsub(L,P*I(:,j));
```

Comment: The error message is clear: when calling the `forsub` function in the assignment `Y = forsub(L,P*I(:,j));`, you did not declared what is this function. You have not provided the code for this function, so you should write the cod for the forward and backward substitution algorithms and save them in the same folder you are trying to run your function.

Comment: @Thales Oh Okay, Thank You!

Comment: you are trying to to a matrix inversion by factorization... A-1 is a bit misleading in your title;)